# Discord bot I made with node.js is saying "ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a discord bot and am trying to disconnect everyone who deafens themselves. I looked it up on the discord.js wiki thing and it looks like Discord.WidgetMember(client, data) is the way to go about it.

Before my code looked like this

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const newState = new Discord.WidgetMember.selfDeaf(client, data);
  if (newState = true) {
    newState.kick();
  }
});
```

That didn't work because it didn't recognize .setDeaf.

So I changed it to this.

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const newState = new Discord.WidgetMember(client, data);
  if (newState.selfDeaf = true) {
    newState.kick();
  }
});
```

That give's me this.

```
const newState = new Discord.WidgetMember(client, data);
                                                  ^
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

I didn't think I had to define data since it's in the parenthesis. I can just barely get by with this code because I'm super new to it. What do I do to fix it?

Comment: _"didn't think I had to define data since it's in the parenthesis"_ that is a function call not a function definition. You are trying to pass information to the function so the variables you use have to exist, check the documentation and see what `data` is expected to hold and pass that

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to use the `Discord.WidgetMember(client, data)` at all... What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Also note that `(newState.selfDeaf = true)` is an assignment not a comparison, you want to use `==` or the more strict `===`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code didn't work is as @PatrickEvans mentioned in their comment:

> That is a function call not a function definition. You are trying to pass information to the function so the variables you use have to exist, check the documentation and see what data it is expected to hold and pass that in.

You were calling a class constructor and you **must** (unless it has no arguments or they are optional) provide the constructor with data it needs to construct the object with. So the variable `data` has to be defined somewhere.

Also the other thing that @PatrickEvans pointed out was that you used an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#assignment_operators) (`=`) instead of [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators) (`==` or `===`). Here `(newState.selfDeaf = true)`, you want to compare the property `.selfDeaf` with the value of `true`, not assign it.

You can access the `.selfDeaf` property directly on the `newMember` object, which is an instance of `GuildMember` or `VoiceState`, depends on the discord.js version you are using. There is no need for `Discord.WidgetMember(client, data)` at all.

For reference see here: [`GuildMember.selfDeaf`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=selfDeaf) or [`VoiceState.selfDeaf`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=selfDeaf).

You are probably looking for something like this:

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (newMember.selfDeaf) {
        newMember.kick();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> I didn't think I had to define data since it's in the parenthesis.

You might be thinking of incoming arguments in a function, rather than passing arguments to a function. In this case the error is telling you that `data` isn't defined when you try to execute `new Discord.WidgetMember(client, data);` The Discord documentation should tell you what you need to pass for this argument.